# Proving Boolean Logic using Axioms

Tags: boolean-algebra, axioms

I am trying to prove boolean logic formulas using axioms. I have a lot of trouble deciding what to do, which axiom to use, when to use it, etc. I've asked others on proving formulas but they have all said that the only way to solve them is by brute force or guessing.

Is this true? Is there a pattern to proving boolean formulas or things to look for?

As an example, I am given the following formula. (Please, don't mind the formatting of implication, equality, etc. I couldn't find the correct symbols.)

> $X \rightarrow (Y \rightarrow Z) = (X \rightarrow Y) \rightarrow (X \rightarrow Z)$ (implication theorem)
>
> $X \rightarrow (\lnot Y \lor Z)$ (distributivity of implication)
>
> $(X \rightarrow \lnot Y) \lor (X \rightarrow Z)$ (implication theorem)
>
> $(~X \lor ~Y) \lor (X \rightarrow Z)$ (De Morgan's Law)
>
> $(X \land Y) \rightarrow (X \rightarrow Z)...~(X \land Y) \lor (X \rightarrow Z)$ (implication theorem)

I have gotten this far and don't know what to do next. Am I even on the right track?

Comment: Why not use a Venn Diagram to get you on the right path?

Comment: @Vimzy How would I apply a venn diagram to this question?

Comment: Well, piece by piece, create the LHS on a Venn Diagram and do the same thing with the right hand side. If the final diagrams are the same, the expressions are equivalent. See: http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/vol_4/chpt_8/3.html

Comment: @Vimzy Ahh, I forgot to mention something. I must use a Hilbert-style proof.